# Smoothly rotate icons via interpolate on MapboxGL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to animate the rotation of my map markers when their values change using MapboxGL's data driven styling and the interpolate expression.  Here is the relevant part of the layer config:

```
{
  layout: {
    'icon-rotate': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['number', ['get', 'winddir'], 0], -180,-180, -90,-90, 0,0, 90, 90, 180, 180]
  }
}
```

The `winddir` property will be a value between -180 & 180.

The markers appear on the map rotated correctly. However, when they change, they "snap" to the next position. I'm thinking I'm not using the "stops" correctly.  [Here are](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate) the `interpolate` docs.

Comment: Can you include a codepen or a video or something? Not clear what you mean by "snap".

Comment: @SteveBennett What I'd like to happen is that when the underlying data for `winddir` for a given point changes from 0 to 15, the marker rotates smoothly from 0° to 1° to 2° all the way to 15°. Instead, right now, the marker goes straight from 0° to 15° ("snaps"). It does not animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-rotate) says:

> Layout property. Optional number. Units in degrees. Defaults to 0. Requires icon-image. Supports interpolate expressions.

It does not include the magic term "transitionable". So, animation transitions are not applied to `icon-rotate`.

Comment: I thought that's what `interpolate` is supposed to do too. The docs say interpolate "Produces continuous, smooth results by interpolating between pairs of input and output values ("stops")."  Whats the difference between "interpolate" and "transitionable"?

Comment: They're totally different. Interpolate means that as some value, like zoom, or a data value changes, then the output changes continuously as a function of that input. Transitionable means that when a change occurs, you get a visual animation between the two states, that lasts about 0.3 seconds by default.